# How to display encoded values from database in GridView Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which displays all data from a database table. However as I have encoded the database values previously the values displayed in the GridView are encoded. What Can I do to decode the values to display them in GridView?

Here are my codes I used for Binding the database to Gridview:

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select bookingName from addCart"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindGrid();
    }
}
```

Which parts of the codes above can I add HttpUtility.HtmlDecode method to display the decoded database i GridView?

Comment: By encoded, do you mean HTML encoded?

Comment: You shouldn't be encoding your data in the database. It should be *encoded* before display, not decoded or else you have XSS issues. The gridview has a way to encode data: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried that htmlencode="false" method, did not work for me. The data still displays the encoded values @Crowcoder

Comment: Yes, Html encoded. I used the method HttpUtility.HtmlEncode method to encode @Shai Cohen

Comment: If you decode you are negating the point of encoding in the first place.

Comment: I encode the database, but when the user wants to read it from the webpage it should be decoded so that it is readable. That's what I want. @Crowcoder

Comment: I understand that's how you want it but that is insecure.

Comment: May I ask how is it insecure? It is the same logic as encrypting the database and only decrypting it when the user wants to view the data from UI, and user must enter password or something in order to view the decrypted data @Crowcoder Anyway I have solved my problem

Comment: Because if someone is able to save, for instance, some javascript in the database it can run on the browser when the gridview is shown. It is basic Cross Site Scripting vulnerability.

Comment: I have already set up my pages to disable Cross Site Scripting before asking this question in stackoverflow. Thank you very much. And I am creating a website, users should not be able to access the database in the first place. @Crowcoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @VDWWD I am able to display my database in it's decoded form:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
Text='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("bookingName").ToString()) %>'>
</asp:Label>        
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: That will work too. However if you are not doing something with the `<span>` element that a `Label` generates you don't really need to put it in a Control.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `TemplateField` you can decode it like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Decoded HTML">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <%# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("column").ToString()) %>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I tried your method and did this: <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("bookingName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <%HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("bookingName").ToString()) %>
                    </ItemTemplate> But I received error from the httputlity line. Did i add the line wrongly? @VDWWD

Comment: I modified your answer into my own default given ItemTemplate and it worked! Will be posting my answer as reference.. Thank you! @VDWWD